# Create database in QT

Tags: qt

Newbie having trouble creating a database here.
Following code compiles ok, but no database is created and I can't find any sqlite file.

```
#include "makeDB.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QtSql>

void makeDB(QString dbName) {
   QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
   db.setHostName("localHost");
   db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
   db.setUserName("logger");
   db.setPassword("logger");
}

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QtSql>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "makeDB.h"
#include "createTable.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  makeDB("log1");

  createTable();

  return a.exec();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!
Waynew
Edit/Delete Message

Answer (score 3):

We can't see what you `createTable()` does, the code that you have never calls `db.open()` most of the QT database and SQL calls return `bool` for success and there is a `lastError()` function for both the `QSqlDatabase` and the `QSqlQuery` calls. Check those if appropriate calls, i.e. `db.open()` and `query.exec()` return false.

e.g.

```
bool makeDB(QString dbName) {
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
  db.setHostName("localHost");
  db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
  bool result = db.open();
  if (result)
  {
    //do more processing
  }
  else
  {
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text()
  }
  return result;
}
```

Also I don't think that SqlLite supports any kind of authentication [this](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/prosupport.html#crypto) seems to indicate that you can secure your db by licensing an extension from the creators of SqlLite.

As to the actual table creation there should be some SQL that is executed that looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE (x int, y varchar);
```

depending on the columns that you actually want.

[This](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) is the respective documentation.